# How to get the logged in member id from PHP / hooks?

Tags: members, hook

Is there a hook-independent way to get the logged in member id inside a hook handler?

Something like a function or a global variable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yip. You're looking for:

```
ee()->session->userdata('member_id');
```

It's in the session class:

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/session.html